# My graph isn't created from my html table

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I would build a bar charts give from a table.

I tried with [this example](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/) but I only get a table in my page.

Here is my code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>            
             <th>Total des Alertes </th>
             <th>Nombre critique</th>
                 <th>Nom d'analyste</th>
            <th>Nombre majeur</th>
            <th>Nombre d'alertes traités</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     {% for liste10 in listes %}

        <tr class="gradeU">
        <td>{{listes11}}</td>
        <td>{{liste10.critique}}</td>
            <td>{{liste10.user_name}} </td>
        <td>{{liste10.majeur}}</td>

        <td> </td>

    </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>


</table>
```

Comment: Did you put `$('example').visualize();` somewhere?

Comment: I have put <script type="text/javascript">
  // Run capabilities test
  enhance({
   loadScripts: [
    {src: 'js/excanvas.js', iecondition: 'all'},
    'js/visualize.jQuery.js',
    'js/example.js'
   ],
   loadStyles: [
    'css/visualize.css',
    'css/visualize-dark.css'
   ] 
  });   
    </script>

Comment: where i Put $('example').visualize();?

Comment: Could you paste the whole code of your page? Not only the table part.

Comment: have you added jquery1.4 file

Answer (score 0):

you will have to import **jquery** and **visualize.jQuery.js** library and than write this in your file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dwpe.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/trunk/charting/js/visualize.jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
   $('table').visualize();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have put <script>
$(function(){
 $('#example').visualize();
});
</script>  but I have juste a table in my page :(

Comment: did u import jquery and visualize.jQuery library?.. without it nothing will work

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/enhance.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/mint.js')}}"></script><script type="text/javascript">
  // Run capabilities test
  enhance({
   loadScripts: [
    {src: 'js/excanvas.js', iecondition: 'all'},
    'js/visualize.jQuery.js',
    'js/example.js'
   ],
   loadStyles: [
    'css/visualize.css',
    'css/visualize-dark.css'
   ] 
  });   
    </script>

Comment: I have this table http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0dZM.png but I do not know how to construct the graph for each user, ie one color for each user

Comment: what do you want on y-axis and x-axis of the graph?